# Start/Stop ECS services to run and stop tasks at defined intervals

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-event-bridge

I have a test automation suite running on my ECS Fargate cluster. The minimum/maximum/desired task are all set to 1. So, after the tests are run, the task stops running but another one gets up and running.

I want to schedule it to run via Eventbridge and stop after it is done, not spin up new tasks unless triggered again. The duration of the task is approx 20 mins and I want it to be run every 2 or 3 hours.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have the minimum set to one if your goal is not to have one running? Have you tried to set it to zero?

Comment: You shouldn't be using ECS Services, just tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you are using the ECS Service feature. You **don't need it** in this case. You need only a task definition and an EventBridge rule with a schedule expression to start one-off tasks using that task definition. See more here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/scheduled_tasks.html.